# Combine a function with a dataframe apply?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I just wanted to know if there is a way to merge this function and the df apply into a single function? Right now, the df[['NewMeterManufacturer'... Sits outside of the function.

```py
def map_manufacturer_model(s):
    s = str(s)
    model = ""
    try:
        manufacturer = manufacturers[s[:4]]
        for k, m in meter_models[s[:4]].items():
            if s[-4:].startswith(k):
                model = m
                break
    except KeyError:
        manufacturer = ""

    return pd.Series({"NewMeterManufacturer": manufacturer, "NewMeterModel": model})


DF[["NewMeterManufacturer", "NewMeterModel"]] = DF["NewSerialNumber"].apply(
    map_manufacturer_model
)
```

Comment: What prevents you to write another function taking additional parameters and wrapping the first one? Or what is your precise question and goal?

Comment: My end goal is to have one function = one task so i can mitigate any issues when sending this code to airflow. As airflow is VM based and dataframes need to moved to storage and cant be passed to another function like base python allows.

Comment: so the end goal of this function is to apply the function to the dataframe, and then store to some storage to be called for the next function, however before we do that, i need to solve this first!

Comment: are you looking for something like `def foo(df, cols_left, cols_right): df[cols_left] = df[cols_right].apply(map_manufacturer_model)`?

Comment: @timgeb Could you explain what this means a so i can fully understand? Are you saying to run two functions and call this first function into a second one?

Comment: @MizanurChoudhury sorry I don't know where to start this explanation if you don't know how functions work.